# Adding entire musical concepts to expand vocabulary

Tags: phonology, vocabulary, music

I want my language, Syn, to be as precise, efficient, unambiguous, and aesthetic as humanely possible. To do that, I think even the texture, dynamics, rhythm, and the likes should be accounted for.

As far as I know, only Mandarin incorporates changes in intonation corresponding with a different meaning of the same spoken word, but even that can be hard to notice for non-speakers.

---

Are there any other languages that incorporte musical concepts?

If there are, how did people manage to use those concepts?

If there are none yet, will such a language possess an added difficulty when speaking it?

---

I imagine that the native speakers of Syn would be naturally adept in tone recognition, and every conversation would seem like an a capella get-together.

Comment: What you describe Mandarin as is called a tonal language. Tonality is pretty common in natural languages. Note that you also use intonation in English in a more restricted manner (e.g. "You can." vs. "You can?")

Comment: Note that some people would consider that [ambiguity *is* aesthetic](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/a/177/113).

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of [tonal languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_(linguistics))

Answer (score 4):

There is a precedent for the use of a musical tone scale in constructed languages: [Solresol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solresol), a philosophical language constructed in the 19th century. Some natural languages also have a whistled mode, most notably [El Silbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silbo_Gomero) and [Pirahã](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirah%C3%A3).

I am not aware of a language—neither natural nor constructed—that incorporates the concept of rhythm or other musical concepts.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The *Yllurian Spell Singing Language*  incorporates as part of its magical effect the use of ordinary lexicon & grammar with musical pitch & rhythm.

As a ritual language, for any given spell to be effective, not only must the text be written and sung, but the tones & rhythms must be notated as well. The text may be sung or the notes may be played upon a flute constructed to conform to the particular mode of the music.

You can read a little about the Spell Singing Language [*here*](http://world.conlang.org/index.php?title=Yllurian_Spell_Singing_Language).

Comment: Where can I find sample scripts of Yllurian?

Comment: @Kyle Zabala --- Thanks for asking! Link to article added.